# Python command line call to main does not go into main function

Tags: python, arguments, python-3.6, program-entry-point

I have a python file with the following main function:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = docopt(__doc__)

    print('source: %s' % args['--src'])
    print('target: %s' % args['--tgt'])
```

Now when I call this function:

```
python test.py --src file1 --tgt file2
```

I get:

```
Usage:
    test.py --src=<file> --tgt=<file>
Options:
    -h --help            Show this screen.
    --src=<file>         src
    --tgt=<file>         tgt
```

But the main function logic is just not called. How to fix this?

I tried:

```
python test.py --src=file1 --tgt=file2
```

but I get the same result.

Comment: `python test.py --src=file1 --tgt=file2`

Comment: yes, i tried that..same result..

Comment: You might also benefit from the `pdb` library. A few well placed pdb.set_trace() calls will make determining your code's behavior a lot easier. If you place one before your args= call you will find that it does enter that if statement.

Comment: @Erich Thanks, I put set_trace just below args = docopt(__doc__) .. it enters main but logic after that does not get called..

Comment: It *is* being entered, because otherwise `docopt` wouldn't fail to parse the arguments and produce the usage message. So, what *is* your docstring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out your docstring. I believe the issue is due to a missing line break between `Usage` and `Options` sections there.

I tried this docstring and it worked fine:

```
"""
Usage:
    test.py --src=<file> --tgt=<file>

Options:
    -h --help       Show this screen.
    --src<file>     src
    --tgt=<file>    tgt
"""
from docopt import docopt

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = docopt(__doc__)
    print('source: %s' % args['--src'])
    print('target: %s' % args['--tgt'])
```